# Change combo box value when selecting a value from another combo box

Tags: c#, sql, combobox

I am new to C# and wanted to throw this out there.  I have a program for time scheduling of certain objects.  combobox3 for example with have a list of times that are populated from a sql datasource that I want a user to be able to select from.  combobox15 has a list of objects to be scheduled.

When someone selects an object in combobox 15 I would like to pull in a current scheduled time from another sql datasource and place it in combobox3.  I would also like the user to be able to see the list of times from the first sql datasource in order to change them.

I can't seem to get both of these data sources to work, let alone get the value to change in combobox3 when I select an object in combobox15.  Any suggestions?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    SqlConnection cs1 = new SqlConnection("data source=server1; initial catalog=mycatalog; integrated security=false; user id=user;password=password");

    SqlConnection cs2 = new SqlConnection("data source=server1; initial catalog=mycatalog; integrated security=false; user id=user;password=password");

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cs1.Open();

        SqlCommand sc1 = new SqlCommand("select times from myschedule.dbo.timelist", cs1);
        SqlDataReader reader;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        reader = sc1.ExecuteReader();
        dt.Columns.Add("times", typeof(string));
        dt.Load(reader);
        comboBox3.ValueMember = "times";
        comboBox3.DataSource = dt;

        cs1.Close();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void comboBox15_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                      
           cs2.Open();

            SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("select time_from from otherdb.dbo.time   where object = 'time'", cs1);

            SqlDataReader reader;
            reader = sc.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("time_from", typeof(string));
            dt.Load(reader);
            comboBox3.ValueMember = "time_from";
            comboBox3.DataSource = dt;

            cs2.Close();
    }

    private bool comboBox15_SelectedIndexChanged()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }     
}
```

Comment: check this http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2012/07/cascading-combobox-in-winforms-windows-forms.html

Comment: Could you show us your code? Also, it would probably be helpful to us (and to yourself) if you gave your combo boxes meaningful names instead of just using the default comboBoxX names.

Comment: Also, just to clarify I can get the data sources to work one at a time, but not both at the same time.